# Accordion layout does not show the stacked closed panels at bottom

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Usually an accordion panel will expand the first child panel and the rest panels' title will be stacked at the bottom. But for me **there is no panels' title visible in the bottom**. its just empty.  See the screen shot.

[image]

But I am actually have 3 form panels there.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        region: 'center',
        html: '<h3>Some text. Lorem ipsom?</h3>'
    },{
        region: 'east',
        layout: 'accordion',
    width: 300,
    items: [loginForm, regForm, passForm]
    }]
});
```

Why is this? how do I fix this?

I am using `Ext 4.0.7`.  Full source can be found [here](http://pastie.org/5083527).

Comment: Check the `WebIM.createForm()` function. Forms created using the method are causing the problem. `loginForm` is created normally. That displays properly.

Comment: @VarunAchar the createForm function is just a wrapper that creates a form with some common config.  loginForm is appearing because its the first item. I think the problem is I am using viewport.

Comment: Nope. It isn't the viewport. I just tested it. Accordion works with viewport

Comment: I know accordion works with viewport. But see the code carefully. There is an existing 'div' in the body and viewport is rendered having that div on top. So I think the whole viewport is moved down a bit!

Comment: @VarunAchar I have answered my own question. Check it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the header div element. Normally viewport is rendered to `document.body`. If it finds any existing element it can not replace it. Rather it appends the output. So what happened here is 2 components/elements are rendered. First the existing header div and then the viewport. The header div takes some space on top of the viewport. This same space is then get invisible on viewport on the bottom. To solve it, put the existing elements html as a panel in viewport. Keep its region to `north`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
            region: 'north',
            html: header.html // <------- Add html of `div#head` here
            height: 300  // <------- put a height too.

        },{
            region: 'center',
            html: '<h3>Some text. Lorem ipsom?</h3>'
        },{
            region: 'east',
            layout: 'accordion',
            width: 300,
            items: [
                    loginForm, regForm, passForm
            ]
        }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope in Accordion Layout you shoud not give height for a panel which you have given for loginForm.

height: 150,